# Outlook 2013 HTML email overlapping text issue

Tags: html, email, html-email, outlook-2013

I'm having an issue with a nested table containing an image and caption, where the inline text next to it is being overlapped by some whitespace in Outlook 2013.

Screen here:  [image]

Here's my code:

```
  <td class="post" align="left" style="padding-right:18px;">
    <!--<a name="2013310049996"></a>-->
    <font style="font-family:Georgia,serif;color:#585555;font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;line-height:25px;display:block;float:left;padding-bottom:12px;"><a href="http://www.modernhealthcare.com/article/20131004/BLOG/310049996?AllowView=VW8xUmo5Q21TcWJOb1gzb0tNN3RLZ0h0MWg5SVgra3NZRzROR3l0WWRMWGFWUDBGRWxyd01qUzMyWmFyNTNnWUpiV24=&utm_source=link-20131004-BLOG-310049996&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=dose" target="_blank" style="font-family:Georgia,serif;color:#585555;font-size:22px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;line-height:25px;"><span style="font-family:Georgia,serif;color:#585555;font-size:22px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;line-height:25px;">MemorialCare, UC Irvine announce plan to open primary-care centers&#8212;with interoperability</span></a></font>
    <table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" callpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" valign="top" align="center" style="border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#ffffff;"><tr><td width="100%" height="4"></td></tr></table>
    <table width="102" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" valign="top" align="left" style="border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#ffffff;text-align:left;margin-right:12px;">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <img src="http://www.modernhealthcare.com/apps/pbcsi.dll/storyimage/CH/20131004/BLOG/310049996/AR/0/AR-310049996.jpg?cci_ts=20131004141411&MaxW=90&MaxH=125&border=0" border="0" alt="" style="line-height:50%;margin:0;padding:0;margin-bottom:6px;" />
            </td>
        <tr>
    </table>
    <font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#7b7a77;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;">
    <!-- SUMMARY -->
    There has been a lot of complaining lately about the lack of interoperability in healthcare information technology and how the inability of computers to communicate with each other impedes organizing population health-improvement systems. But two Southern California organizations that just announced a deal to open a string of primary-care health centers said interoperability concerns will not stand in the way.
    <!-- FULL STORY LINK-->
    <br/><a style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#1f5591;font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;line-height:17px;" target="_blank" href="http://www.modernhealthcare.com/article/20131004/BLOG/310049996?AllowView=VW8xUmo5Q21TcWJOb1gzb0tNN3RLZ0h0MWg5SVgra3NZRzROR3l0WWRMWGFWUDBGRWxyd01qUzMyWmFyNTNnWUpiV24=&utm_source=link-20131004-BLOG-310049996&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=dose&utm_source=link-20131004-BLOG-310049996&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=dose"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#1f5591;font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;line-height:17px;">FULL STORY <span style="color:#56c7a3;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">&raquo;</span></span></a>
    <!-- BYLINE -->
    <br/><span style="font-family:Georgia,serif;color:#858585;font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;line-height:17px;"><a style='font-family:Georgia,serif;color:#858585;font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;line-height:17px;' href="mailto:arobeznieks@modernhealthcare.com">Andis Robeznieks</a><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-style:normal;color:#56c7a3;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;&raquo;</span></span>
    </font>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561711/outlook-2013-rendering-issue-nested-table-truncating-adjacent-text?rq=1

Comment: try adding "mso-table-rspace" to the left-aligned-table like this: <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style=mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:7pt;">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove all margins. Outlook dosnt support it at all.
2. Try to make a `display: inline-block` and `padding-right: 6px` on the `<img>`

Comment: Thanks.  Apparently, setting align="left" to the parent table will fix this same issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561711/outlook-2013-rendering-issue-nested-table-truncating-adjacent-text?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Margin is not supported in Outlook. Try using padding instead.

Also, declaring the width and height on your image may help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll replace my margins with padding.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few potential issues, although I've never had outlook display anything over another element.

1 - On the `img` tag you have `line-height` set to 50%. Why?

2 - You have an empty TD above the image, as a spacer I presume. On that one you should set the style attribute to `line-height:4px; font-size:4px;`, and throw an `&nbsp;` in the `td`. Outlook 2013 will make your empty cells 15px high otherwise.

3 - don't nest your `span` tags. Close one, start the other.

4 - Your image does indeed need `display:inline-block;`.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.  The line-height:50%; being applied to images was for a web-based client fix that displayed gaps between images... I believe it was specific to Gmail.

Comment: @cdunn `style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;"` is all you need for images to prevent gaps.